# Good math libraries for haskell like pylab and scipy for python?

Tags: haskell, matplotlib

Recently I've picked up Haskell. I've found that some basic math algorithms I write recursively in Haskell actually run quicker, so I want to try this out for a bit.

I've looked around personally, and I can't really find a library similar to pylab and scipy for Haskell. Does anyone know something that is similar to it or other math libraries which could be helpful?

All the math problems I do are in relation to nonlinear ordinary differential equations and partial differential equations, if that helps someone point me in a good direction.

Basically a library that has matrix, graphing, trig, exponential functions, etc.

Comment: There's a matlab package.

Comment: Also, I don't know where you've looked, but most Haskell packages are available on Hackage.

Comment: If you're familiar with IPython you'll probably like [IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell).

Comment: @Bakuriu Too bad it's not supported on windows, hopefully the new [Project Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter) will help to alleviate these pains for those of us who are stuck with windows at work.

Comment: You may be interested in the recent [LAPACK bindings](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lapack).

Answer (score 3):

There's [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) which includes ODEs.

It uses BLAS and LAPACK for the linear algebra, similar to scipy.

Comment: ODE solvers are now in the `hmatrix-gsl` package.